# Run time cost of defining a global array?

Tags: c++

I know that the standard guarantees that if I do, for example:

```
int arr[N];
```

Where `N` is a compile time constant, then `arr` is initialized to zero's.
Does this cost `O(N)` to time to initialize or does it rely on the OS to provide a zero page?

Comment: Measure it: memset a non global array

Comment: If you *really* want to worry about this, then why would you think that it's free if the OS does it for you? No matter who does it, the memory has to be set to 0. ;)

Comment: @jalf If it's done regardless of my array definition then I'm getting it for free, aren't I?

Comment: @Shmoopy: It´s not done automtically by the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely accurate - `arr` is *in some cases* initialized to `0`.

```
int arr[42]; //namespace scope

int main()
{
   int arr2[42]; //function scope
}
```

`arr` will be 0-initialized, `arr2` won't be.

`arr1` will typically be embedded in the generated file (exe, obj, dll, whatever) so the There might be a run-time cost because the executable can potentially get bigger and thus take longer to load into memory when the program is loaded, but that's virtually 0.

Since `arr2` isn't initialized to some value, there's no point in talking about the cost.